post-merge hook fails on git pull
I'm getting following error when post-merge hook is getting executed after git pull command:
husky - post-merge script failed (code 1)

Following is the script I'm trying to execute
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

git diff --name-only | grep -q "yarn.lock"
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo "yarn.lock file changed, updating dependencies."
    yarn
    exit 0
else
    echo "yarn.lock file not changed."
fi

When I execute this in the command prompt it executes properly without any error.
